# How to run the same python function simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I want to try and run the function `graph` several times at once in this program, but at the moment it doesn't even run once. Can anyone explain why, and give me some code that fixes it?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import random
from multiprocessing import Process

max_x_val = int(input("What is the maximum x value? "))
max_y_val = int(input("What is the maximum y value? "))
counter = 0


points = int(input("How many points to be plotted? "))
plotted = []

notifications = (input("Do you want to see which point is being ploted?(Y/N) ")).lower() 



def graph(max_x_val, max_y_val, points, plotted, notifications): 
    for i in range (1,points):
        x = random.randint(0,max_x_val)
        y = random.randint(0,max_y_val)

        xstr = str(x)
        ystr = str(y)
        point = (str("(" + xstr + "," + ystr +")"))
        plotted.append(point)
        if (plotted.count(point)) == 1 : c="tab:blue"
        elif (plotted.count(point)) == 2 : c="tab:cyan"
        elif (plotted.count(point)) == 3 : c="tab:green"
        elif (plotted.count(point)) == 4 : c="y"
        elif (plotted.count(point)) == 5 : c="tab:orange"
        elif (plotted.count(point)) >= 6 : c="tab:red"
        plt.scatter(x=x,y=y, c=c)
        if notifications == "y" : print(len(plotted))    
    plt.show()    
    print (plotted)

if __name__=="__main__":
    p1 = Process (target=graph)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process (target=graph)
    p2.start()
```

Comment: you don't even call the `graph` method

Comment: Sorry for the late response - the `graph` function is called at the bottom in `target=graph` and `p1.start()`